# Lefschetz hypersurface theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X \subseteq \mathbf{P}^4$ be a hypersurface over $k$ algebraically closed. Why do we have $Pic(X) = Pic(\mathbf{P}^4)$ by the Lefschetz hypersurface theorem? I only see for $\mu_n$ coefficients $H^1_{et}(X,\mu_n) = H^1_{et}(\mathbf{P}^4,\mu_n)$ and $H^1_{et}(X,\mu_n) = Pic(X)[n]$, so the torsion subgroups are identified. Perhaps $NS(X) = \mathbf{Z}$?

OK, we also have $0 \to Pic(X)/n \to H^2(X,\mu_n) \to Br(X)[n] \to 0$ and the $H^2$ coincide, so $Pic(-) \otimes \mathbf{Z}_\ell$ coincide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not aware of a proof along the lines you suggest: Grothendieck in SGA 2, Exposé XII, Corollaire 3.7 gives a proof based on formal schemes.
However, one should take into account that SGA II *precedes* the SGA volumes on étale cohomology so that in a parallel universe  where EGA is completed (and includes all of SGA, just as intended by Grothendieck) there might be an étale-cohomological proof of Grothendieck-Lefschetz.

Over $\mathbb C$ there **is** a proof of the theorem you mention in the spirit of your suggestion.
It is based on the long exact sequence derived from the exponential exact sequence $$0\to \underline {\mathbb Z}\to \mathcal O_Y\to \mathcal O_Y^\ast\to 0$$ You have to replace successively $Y$ by $\mathbb P^n$ and $X$ and compare the two long exact sequences.
Remember   that $H^1(X,\mathcal O_X)=H^2(X,\mathcal O_X)=0$, which follows from the exact sequence $$ 0\to O_{\mathbb P^4}(-d)\to \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^4}\to \mathcal O_X\to 0   $$(where $d$ is the degree of $X$), again by taking cohomology.

**Remark**
Some readers might ask why we have this strange hypothesis on the dimension of projective  space.
The reason is that the the theorem is completely false in $\mathbb P^1$, $\mathbb P^2$ and  $\mathbb P^3$: a curve in $\mathbb P^2$ has in general a huge Picard group (actually an algebraic variety) and a smooth quadric in $\mathbb P^3$ already has Picard group $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$.   (Need I recall that $\text {Pic}(\mathbb P^m)=\mathbb Z$ ?)
 I'll let these readers  ponder on hypersurfaces of $\mathbb P^1 \dots$